# SpineJS stack doesn't add active class to controllers

Tags: spine.js

```
Spine = require('spine')
Welcome = require('controllers/welcome')
Signup = require('controllers/signup')

class Main extends Spine.Stack
  controllers:
    welcome: Welcome
    signup: Signup

  default: 'signup'

  routes:
    '/welcome': 'welcome'
    '/signup': 'signup'

module.exports = Main
```

The `welcome` and `signup` controllers just render a view so I can understand how the stack works:

```
Spine = require('spine')

class Welcome extends Spine.Controller
  className: 'welcome'

  constructor: ->
    super
    @active @render

  render: ->
    console.log 'welcome render function'
    @html require('views/welcome')()

module.exports = Welcome
```

and then per [stack docs](http://spinejs.com/docs/stacks), I added this to my css:

```
.stack > *:not(.active) {
  display: none
}
```

I purposefully have the signup controller do `@navigate('/welcome')` instead of rendering its view to see how I would control the stack. The `console.log` statement in welcome's render function does get called, however welcome's `<div>` doesn't have the `active` class added to it, and because of the above CSS, isn't shown.

I've re-read the docs a few times, googled around, and am not sure what I'm missing. Why isn't the active class being added to the welcome el?

Comment: I narrowed down this question to the constructor of one of my controllers binding a function to the `active` event and that binding function actually getting called, which happens before the stack activates the default controller.

Comment: I realized a better way to do what I'm trying to do though - I overwrote the constructor of my stack:

    constructor: ->
      super
      if @verify_user() then @navigate('/welcome') else @navigate('signup')

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is that you're calling `render` as part of the `active` event, which is happening after the class is added.  Since `render` calls `@html`, it would replace the HTML that had the class added.

As an aside, with spine I've found that reading the source code can help immensely.  It's a tiny framework.  See https://github.com/spine/spine/blob/dev/src/manager.coffee for the relevant code for stacks.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I don't think that's it.

I tried only rendering the view in the constructor and nothing changed. Also, the Contacts example does the same thing with their Show and Edit controllers in the Main stack - binding render to the active event (http://spinejs.com/docs/example_contacts)